# Firebase auth does not persist in React web app (localhost:3000)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I setup Firebase auth (password and Google) and can login but the auth state is lost on reload. I can see cookie stored in the local storage.

1. I setup my listener:

```
export function useAuth() {
    const auth = getFirebaseAuth();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(auth.currentUser);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = getFirebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            console.log(user);
            setUser(user);
        });
        return unsub;
    }, []);

    return user;
}
```

2. This is how I setup an app:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);

const firebaseAuth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp);
firebaseAuth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);

export function getFirebaseAuth() {
    return firebaseAuth;
}
```